# How to format a Windows Pen drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-drive, format, read-only

I currently have a Windows 10 pen drive that isn't in use at the moment. I try to format the drive on disks, and the terminal using `mkfs.vfat /dev/sdc1` and all I get is;

```
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
mkfs.vfat: unable to open /dev/sdc1: Read-only file system
```

Is there a way to format this to any file system? I'd like to use it for other things.

[Disks view of the drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDKjQ.png)

Comment: have you tried gparted ... try deleting the partitions ... since its bootable install drive or something like that .. it will probably have more than one .. after the USB drive is completely void of partitions you can create a new one and format it to your liking

Comment: gparted error, "Can't write to dev/sdc, because it is opened read-only"

Comment: There's a reason why I like and use linux more than windows

Comment: Maybe try using GParted to create a new MBR partition table?

Comment: does the USB have some special 'hardware' lock on it ... how is it opened as read only if you arent mounting it... you did say " a Windows Pen Drive" .. instead of a usb drive .. is this a special thing you got from Microsoft or is it just a USB drive

Comment: @JohnOrion the answer is simple. Microsoft.

Comment: @ WJAndrea I don't know how to add images in comments but it errors everytime I format to any fs or try to resize partition. Its the same as the comment above from gparted

Comment: @rvcabc ok you got it from Microsoft ... so its probably not a USB drive .. its probably a ROM (read only memory) ... just a chip that has the OS install programmed on it and doesn't have any capability of writing to it. that would be my best guess.

Comment: You are sure that you haven't currently mounted /dev/sdc1?

Comment: His image shows that its not mounted but "read only"  I think it's a ROM not a writeable usb

Comment: @muclux I have mounted then formated, failed. Unmounted then formated, fail. I think JohnOrion is correct and that it's not really a pen drive but a rom. It makes sense. It has windows 10 on it and it's 16GiB worth of data and it was created by Microsoft.

Comment: lol but then again .. if its just a windows install .. it should be less in size ... unless they just got a bunch of 16g chips .. usually the windows install usbs are like 4gig but .. since you said its from Microsoft ... its possible they did something to it so its unwriteable

Comment: It has windows 10 64 and 32 home and pro. it's only using 14 GiB. What I don't understand is the File System. Why is it using 'W95 Fat32 (LBA)'? to my understanding, that's old, like 1995 fs old.

Comment: Maybe it's like a raid setup. The only way to replace it is to deactivate the raid, or thats how its been working for me.

Comment: I think its for compatibility for bios .. even when you create you own on a flash drive .. they tell you to format to fat32

Comment: @rvcabc I'm talking about creating a new partition table, which is one layer below partitioning. See instructions [here](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual#gparted-create-partition-table), though I assume it's going to fail based on the other comments here.

Comment: @WJAndrea It was worth a shot but yeah it failed. Not the end of the world, unless Microsoft had it's way. :P

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft made their Windows 10 pen drives read-only to prevent using it for anything other than the intention (based on the comments on the question).